# Prolog recursive program returning too many results

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have a Prolog program which is meant to find the sum of the squares of all the numbers in a list divisible by three or five. However it returns more than one result and I'm not sure why.

```
% --divisibility tests--

div_test(N):-
    % divisible by three?
    0 is N mod 3.
div_test(N):-
    % divisible by five?
    0 is N mod 5.

% sum of an empty list is zero (base case)
square_sum([], Sum):-
    Sum is 0.

% --recursive cases
square_sum([Head | Tail], Sum) :-
    div_test(Head),
    square_sum(Tail, TempSum),
    Sum is Head*Head + TempSum.

square_sum([Head | Tail], Sum) :-
    square_sum(Tail, TempSum),
    Sum is TempSum.
```

Given the following input:

```
?-square_sum([1,2,3,4,5],Sum).
```

I get the following output:

```
Sum = 34 ;
Sum = 9 ;
Sum = 25 ;
Sum = 0.
```

34 is the only output I should get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% --recursive cases
square_sum([Head | Tail], Sum) :-
    div_test(Head),
    square_sum(Tail, TempSum),
    Sum is Head*Head + TempSum.

square_sum([Head | Tail], Sum) :-
    square_sum(Tail, TempSum),
    Sum is TempSum.
```

In the second rule you don't test if div_test succeeds.
You can either **add a cut** (!) after div_test(Head), in the first rule or add **\+div_test(Head)**, in the second rule.

You use SWI-Prolog, so you can use module lambda.pl found there  http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl and write

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
div_test(N):-
    % divisible by three?
    0 is N mod 3.
div_test(N):-
    % divisible by five?
    0 is N mod 5.

square_sum(Lst, Sum) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^((div_test(X); div_test(X))
              ->  Z is Y + X*X
              ;   Z = Y), Lst, 0, Sum).
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about the cut in prolog haha (I'm new to Prolog). I'll have a look into the lambda module :)